# Составление планов на будущее.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, php, css, django

Решил составить небольшие планы на ближайшее будущее и хочу с вами, дорогие друзья, посоветоваться.
Есть несколько вариантов и нужно выбрать что - то, что сейчас актуально и максимально востребованно (в том числе полезно в команде). Я для себя накидал пару вариантов, но мне так же очень интересны Ваши.
 1. Учиться верстать (что мне не очень нравится и даже угнетает, хотя, местами получается неплохо), после чего учиться работать с ЦМСками (натягивать вёрстку, писать плагины и прочее) и... Вроде всё, дальше тут некуда развиваться, походу.
 2. Оставить вёрстку как есть, на среднем уровне и изучать PHP (знаю на уровне "ниже среднего"), после того, как почувствую себя уверенно можно будет взяться за какой - нибудь микрофреймворк/фреймворк.
 3. Начать изучать dJango или Рельсы (отзываются о них очень хорошо, но разницы особой не вижу) и работать только с этими фреймворками.
 4. Ну и в конец безумный для меня вариант (ибо кажется непростым. Но, не исключаю, что на деле будет проще) - браться за C# и осваивать платформу .net.
Вот несколько путей моего "развития". Нужно так же учитывать, что базовые навыки у меня есть (HTML + CSS, JS, PHP, etc...).
Очень интересно ваше мнение!

Comment: Кстати, забыл отметить то, что по началу хочу работать на фрилансе. Так же подскажите, что лучше изучать для работы на фрилансах.

Comment: Фреймворки учаться по туториалам на оффициальных сайтах. После того как пройдете туториал начните пилить свой собственный настоящий проект. В процессе приобретете кучу знаний не только по фреймворку, но и по языку(документация, гугл, hashcode.ru, askdev.ru, sctackoverflow.com, ну и конечно форумы). Если хотите дальше развиваться с документацией придется работать иначе никак.  Работа с фреймворком эта работа с документацией и как правило на английском. Книг, как правило, мало. Если есть, то на английском.

Comment: Это по началу кажется, что документация это муторная вещь, но в процессе вы привыкнете к ней и не сможете без неё уже. И произойдет это не позже чем через месяц, при каждодневной работе)) Так, что вперед.

Comment: Ну, тогда придётся немало потрудиться. ^^"
И самый последний вопрос, насколько хорошо я должен верстать, будучи программистом? Покажите пару примеров того, как Вам кажется, как должен верстать PHP разработчик.

Comment: Как минимум вы должны уметь верстать трехколончатый сайт. А если чисто по моему то верстка для программиста это само собой разумеющееся, т.е. в совершенстве знать должен.

Comment: Немало трудится придется всегда коль решили этим заниматься. Каждый день по несколько часов. Путь программиста  - это путь очень тяжелый, но приятный.

Comment: @z_coder, согласен, программист должен знать верстку как минимум на твердую четверку. У нас в веб-студии появился новенький веб-программист, который заявил, что ему для программирования верстка не нужна. Я тихо поржал, а потом смотрел как он не может надеть верстку на цмс-ку. Так что решайте =)

Comment: Надеюсь, и это с практикой получу...
А как насчёт Java Script? В том числе и jQuery?

Comment: Составлять серьёзные план на будущее лучше начиная с конца - где хочешь оказаться по выполнении всех пунктов плана, тогда и будет о чем советоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если на ближайшее то почти все верно спланировал. Только когда дойдешь до php всрстку оставлять не нужно. И так с любыми пройденными технологиями. Пока изучаешь новое параллельно совершенствуешь старое, иначе не преуспеешь.

Comment: До PHP я уже давно дошёл. Иногда верстаю, что бы не отвыкать.
Думаю, могу сделать какой - нибудь самописный блог или даже магазин. Что ещё нужно знать PHP программисту, или этих знаний будет достаточно, что бы перейти к фреймворкам?

Comment: Если знаете ООП часть php то вперед к фреймворкам. Рекомендую Yii, а после этого уже можно phalcon.

Comment: Асли не знаете ООП то надо учить ООП.

Comment: Знаю ООП только в теории.
Но, надеюсь, при работе с фреймворками получу и практические знания.
А для использования phalcon нужны знания по C?

Comment: желательны, но ни в коем случае не обязательны.

Comment: я поэтому рекомендовал сначала yii потом phalcon. Cи тоже знать очень даже не плохо бы.

Comment: Думаю, можно будет и его изучить. Давно это планировал. Хорошо, а какую литературу посоветуете по этим фреймворкам? Кроме официальной документации, ибо её я не особо люблю. Особенно, если она на английском.

Comment: @NyaXA, почитайте книгу Мэтта Зандстры - PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4212311 . Золотая книга. Очень четко описано ООП

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю.

Comment: @NyaXA выучить английский язык и полюбить официальную документацию заодно включите в "список"